# Morphisms into projective $n$-space defined by invertible sheaf and global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-space

In my algebraic geometry class we had a theorem that for a scheme $X$ over an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} A$ giving a morphism $X \to \mathbb{P}^n_A$ is the same as giving an invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ and $n + 1$ global sections $s_0, \dotsc , s_n \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{L})$ which generate $\mathcal{L}$.
In the proof we then defined $X_{s_i} = \{ x \in X \mid (s_i)_x \notin \mathfrak{m}_x \mathcal{L}_x\}$ and morphisms
$$
  f_i \colon X_{s_i} \to \mathbb{P}_A^n
$$
by
\begin{align*}
  A\Bigl[ \frac{x_0}{x_i}, \dotsc ,\frac{x_n}{x_i} \Bigr]
  &\to \Gamma(X_{s_i}, \mathcal{O}_{X_{s_i}}) \,, \\[0.5em]
  \frac{x_j}{x_i}
  &\mapsto s_j\vert_{X_{s_i}} (s_i\vert_{X_{s_i}})^{-1} \,.
\end{align*}
Here I am confused, the $s_j$ are global sections of $\mathcal{L}$ but why are then the $s_j\vert_{X_{s_i}} (s_i\vert_{X_{s_i}})^{-1} \in \Gamma(X_{s_i}, \mathcal{O}_{X_{s_i}})$?
Im sorry if any of the notation is unclear, please ask and I will explain what is meant.

Comment: The ration of two sections of a line bundle is a rational function.

Comment: You find a more "scheme theoretic" construction of the Segre embedding here which may be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4117064/stacks-project-construction-of-segre-embedding-a-clarification/4123144#4123144

Comment: @hm2020 ok thank you this helped me quite a bit, for others in Hartshorne II 7.1 , goes a tiny bit more into detailed, and I found the post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659200/hartshorne-page-150-theorem-7-1?rq=1 which disusses exactly the same problem.